# Opening NEF files in older versions of Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, raw

My camera is `Nikon D-810` and I shot in `RAW` and my software is `Adobe Creative Cloud` so it is always updated and open `RAW` files with no problem. 
**But** Now I have given my `RAW` files that are `.NEF` to another photographer that shoots `Canon 5D Mark II` and uses a `Photoshop CS6` that is **pirated**! So she can't update the software. I am trying to convince her to upgrade to Creative Cloud but in the mean time!
How can she use my files **without** updating? Is there a way I can kind of **downgrade** my `NEF` files that she can still use in Camera RAW?

[image]

[image]

Comment: My desire to write any answers to help software pirates is somewhere below zero.

Comment: He could have written that the person was using CS6 and unwilling to pay for an upgrade or move to a subscriotion model, without commenting on how much she paid for her extant version. Avoiding the "photoshop tax" when buying a new camera has always been a real issue.  Perhaps the poster is expressing his own negative opinion on his friend's piracy by mentioning it here when it could have been avoided.  (To the OP) you *could* edit the question if you want to keep a good resource for this issue here and without the tarnish)

Comment: @JDługosz Sure. I'm just explaining why *I'm* not going to answer this *specific* question.

Answer (score 3):

Use Adobe's free (and up-to-date version) DNG converter. It will import your raw files, and being a current version, knows about that camera.  It writes DNG files which include necessary profile information directly in the file, so older versions of Adobe products can open them just fine.

Comment: If the pirate person :D has some photo configs that applies to all her RAW files ( like a general setting for importing portrait shots in a wedding to have a good base line for all of them for start ), then if converted to DNG will she still be able to apply those settings to them?

Comment: Dng can be opened in photoshop using the RAW loader, so all those veatures are available.  I don't know what "photo configs" mean, but whatever you do in photoshop won't suddenly not work because the image was loaded from a particular file type.

Answer (score 1):

**Using a pirated software is indeed the wrong way (for various reasons) and she should solve this as soon as possible.**

However if there's a need for a fast solution until she upgrades, she might use e.g. [RAW Thereapee](http://rawtherapee.com/downloads) (available for Windows, MAC and Linux; Nikon d-180 is supported in current version) to process RAWs into uncompressed/lossless compressed HDR TIFFs (48bpp, 16b/channel) and open them in her temporary Photoshop instead.

Comment: If the pirate person :D has some photo configs that applies to all her RAW files ( like a general setting for importing portrait shots in a wedding to have a good base line for all of them for start ), then if converted to HDR TIFFs will she still be able to apply those settings to them?